# Удаление дублирующихся данных в односвязном списке

Tags: c++, алгоритм, list, список, односвязный-список

Дан отсортированный список, необходимо удалить узлы с дублирующимися данными. Решил задачу таким образом:

```
SinglyLinkedListNode* removeDuplicates(SinglyLinkedListNode* head) {
    if (!head || !head->next) {
        return head;
    }

    SinglyLinkedListNode *temp = head;
    SinglyLinkedListNode *toDeleteNode = nullptr;
    while (temp->next != nullptr) {
        if (temp->data == temp->next->data) {
            toDeleteNode = temp->next;
            temp->next = temp->next->next;
            delete [] toDeleteNode;
            continue;            
        }
        if (temp->next != nullptr) {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
    return head;
}
```

Далее захотел избавиться от `continue` и написал следующее:

```
SinglyLinkedListNode* removeDuplicates(SinglyLinkedListNode* head) {
    if (!head || !head->next) {
        return head;
    }

    SinglyLinkedListNode *temp = head;
    SinglyLinkedListNode *toDeleteNode = nullptr;
    while (temp->next != nullptr) {
        while (temp->data == temp->next->data) {
            toDeleteNode = temp->next;
            temp->next = temp->next->next;
            delete [] toDeleteNode;            
        }
        if (temp->next != nullptr) {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
    return head;
}
```

---

**Вопрос:** Почему второе решение неверно, какие ошибки я допустил, и как переписать это решение чтобы оно работало.
Спустя некоторое время додумался избавится от `continue` просто 2 if заменив на конструкцию `if-else`:

```
if (temp->data == temp->next->data) {
    toDeleteNode = temp->next;
    temp->next = temp->next->next;
    delete [] toDeleteNode;                        
} else {
    temp = temp->next;
}
```

Comment: А почему не использовать `std::list`? Уж точно полезней для реальной жизни.

Comment: @andy.37        В образовательных планах. Да и тут у меня проблема не со списками, а в пониманию алгоритма, который на листочке работает, а так нет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема этого фрагмента кода

```
while (temp->next != nullptr) {
    while (temp->data == temp->next->data) {
        toDeleteNode = temp->next;
        temp->next = temp->next->next;
        delete [] toDeleteNode;            
    }
    if (temp->next != nullptr) {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
```

состоит в том, что внутреннее предложение `while` приводит к неопределенному поведению, так как в нем нет проверки на то, что temp->next не равно null-указателю. То есть условие

```
temp->data == temp->next->data
```

является неполным.

При такой реализации придется дублировать условие внешнего `while` цикла во внутреннем `while` цикле:

```
while (temp->next != nullptr && temp->data == temp->next->data) {
```

Также непонятно, почему вы используете оператор `delete []` вместо оператора `delete` для указателей на элементы списка.

Если сохранить ваше объявление функции, то ее определение может выглядеть следующим образом

```
SinglyLinkedListNode * removeDuplicates( SinglyLinkedListNode  *head )
{
    if ( head )
    {
        for ( SinglyLinkedListNode *current = head; current->next; )
        {
            if ( current->data == current->next->data )
            {
                SinglyLinkedListNode *tmp = current->next;
                current->next = current->next->next;
                delete tmp;
            }
            else
            {
                current = current->next;
            }
        }
    }

    return head;
}
```

Comment: delete [] поставил так просто проверял какая разница в удалении одного элемента.

Answer (score 1):

1. Вы передаете в функцию указатель и возвращаете его в таком
   же состоянии. Это конечно бессмыленно...   Логичнее, если ваша
   функция не должна ничего возвращать или возвращать указатель на
   последный удаленный узел (не думаю, что второй вариант кому то
   понадобится).
2. Если же вы все таки решили возвращать этот указатель, то  не нужно
   возвращать его в условии и без условия, так что:

   ```
   if (!head || !head->next) {
       return head;
   }
   ```

Совершенно лишные строки.

Ну, а если  попытаться написать решение поизящней, то я бы написал так:

```
void removeDuplicates(SinglyLinkedListNode* head) {   
    if (head) {
        SinglyLinkedListNode *first = head,
                *second = first->next;                
        while (second && second->next) {
            if (first->data == second->data ) {
                first->next = second->next;
                delete second; 
            }             
            else 
                first = second;            
            second = first->next;                          
    }     
}
```

Comment: Мне не понятно как мы получим доступ к second->next если до этого выполнили delete second. Я как понимаю этот указатель так и показывает на туже облать, но только освободив облать под указателем, этой облатью  может воспользоваться кто-то иной.

Comment: @Astrodynamic Да, код просто не корректный.

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan Возращающее значение поставленно условием задачи, но так или иначе я бы на простом ходу бы и не заметил что возра какого-либо значения не имеет роли, т.к дублирующеи элементы которые мы удаляем находятся в промежутках и из этого условия вытекает что head таким и останется. А ещё понравилось использование двух указателей читается легче, чем моя змейка head->next->next.

Comment: Вы правы, я забыл строчку

Answer (score -1):

Как в первом так и во втором случае Вы удаляете дубли не принимая во внимание факт, что дубли в списке могут идти и не подряд. Во втором случае есть проблемы в условиях циклов и не везде есть проверки на nullptr.

По хорошему, алгоритм удаления дублей должен быть реализован двумя вложенными циклами: первый используется для фиксации текущего элемента, для которого ищутся дубли, второй - ищет дубли зафиксированного элемента

Comment: "Дан отсортированный список" - первая фраза вопроса.